# VWAP, daily, weekly and monthly

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have a very old indicator, V2, which isn't possible to update to v5 in pine editor.

Tried many different codes in order to get my vwaps from multiple timeframes, as well as the previous day, week and monthly close. Somehow I am not able to fix it.

Is there perhaps anybody who has this kind of indicator or who could help me with this?

Many thanks in advance

I have used the standard code, updated codes from other, but keep getting errors.

Have add the code in the comments sections, somehow I can't update it in this post

```
//Multi VWAP 
showPrevDVWAP = input(true, type=bool, title="Show Previous Daily close") showPrevWVWAP = input(true, type=bool, title="Show Previous Weekly close") showPrevMVWAP = input(true, type=bool, title="Show Previous Monthly close") 

startD = security(tickerid, "D", time) 
startW = security(tickerid, "W", time) 
startM = security(tickerid, "M", time) 

newSessionD = iff(change(startD), 1, 0) 
newSessionW = iff(change(startW), 1, 0) 
newSessionM = iff(change(startM), 1, 0)

Dvwapsum = iff(newSessionD, hl2*volume, Dvwapsum[1]+hl2*volume) 
Wvwapsum = iff(newSessionW, hl2*volume, Wvwapsum[1]+hl2*volume) 
Mvwapsum = iff(newSessionM, hl2*volume, Mvwapsum[1]+hl2*volume) 

Dvolumesum = iff(newSessionD, volume, Dvolumesum[1]+volume) 
Wvolumesum = iff(newSessionW, volume, Wvolumesum[1]+volume) 
Mvolumesum = iff(newSessionM, volume, Mvolumesum[1]+volume)

Dv2sum = iff(newSessionD, volumehl2*hl2, Dv2sum[1]+volumehl2*hl2) 
Wv2sum = iff(newSessionW, volumehl2*hl2, Wv2sum[1]+volumehl2*hl2) 
Mv2sum = iff(newSessionM, volumehl2*hl2, Mv2sum[1]+volumehl2*hl2) 

Dmyvwap = Dvwapsum/Dvolumesum 
Wmyvwap = Wvwapsum/Wvolumesum 
Mmyvwap = Mvwapsum/Mvolumesum 

Ddev = sqrt(max(Dv2sum/Dvolumesum - DmyvwapDmyvwap, 0)) 
Wdev = sqrt(max(Wv2sum/Wvolumesum - WmyvwapWmyvwap, 0)) 
Mdev = sqrt(max(Mv2sum/Mvolumesum - Mmyvwap*Mmyvwap, 0))

plot(Dmyvwap, title="dVWAP", color=black, style=line, transp=0) 
plot(Wmyvwap, title="wVWAP", color=blue, style=line, transp=0) 
plot(Mmyvwap, title="mVWAP", color=purple, style=line, transp=0) 

Dprevwap = iff(newSessionD, Dmyvwap[1], Dprevwap[1]) 
Wprevwap = iff(newSessionW, Wmyvwap[1], Wprevwap[1]) 
Mprevwap = iff(newSessionM, Mmyvwap[1], Mprevwap[1]) 

plot(showPrevDVWAP ? Dprevwap : na, style=cross, color=close > Dprevwap ? black : black) 
plot(showPrevWVWAP ? Wprevwap : na, style=cross, color=close > Wprevwap ? blue : blue) 
plot(showPrevMVWAP ? Mprevwap : na, style=cross, color=close > Mprevwap ? purple : purple)
```